# Graphics driver ruined Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: drivers, launcher

I installed a driver for the ATI Raedon HD 4000 series, but upon reboot, I found that resolution is considerably smaller, and the launcher and menu bar were gone. I had a few desktop shortcuts, but trying to launch them did nothing. Please help!

Comment: Is the screen only showing part of the desktop? ie Overscan or Underscan

Comment: Only part of it, I think

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it seems you have an overscan issue. That can be fixed in two ways.

Via Catalyst Software installed but that might be hard to access due to the overscan issue.

So type the following into terminal. It sets the overscan value to the correct value.

> `sudo amdconfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0`

Hope that helps you. Reboot recommended after you type the command.

PS: Alt-Ctr-T opens terminal, if window is out of view you can drag it by holding down the alt key while drag the window.